# How to import com.vaadin.ui to Java Project

Tags: java, user-interface, import, vaadin, pom.xml

I started with this tutorial project:

https://vaadin.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-flow/how-to-use-vaadin-flow

and it works. But how to import additional Vaadin libraries. When I add:

```
import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractJavaScriptComponent
```

I get the error message: The import com.vaadin.ui cannot be resolved. But

```
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button
```

works. Do I have to add something to the Pom file? I quite dont know how to install Vaadin properly and use it with maven.

Answer (score 2):

The `AbstractJavaScriptComponent` class doesn't exist in Vaadin 10 or later (it does in Vaadin 8). If you want to integrate JavaScript in Vaadin 10+ see this tutorial: https://vaadin.com/tutorials/calling-java-from-javascript

Comment: Good answer. I am using Vaadin 8.

Comment: If you are starting with Vaadin, I recommend you use Vaadin 12 (and 13 which is going to be released tomorrow). You might want to check this tutorial on Maven as well: https://vaadin.com/tutorials/learning-maven-concepts

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the archetype. I used a quickstart or starter archetype (I cant remember).
After deploying the standard "vaadin-archetype-application" I can import much more Vaadin classes.

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/tutorial.html#tutorial